# How to prompt up user and password prompt for executable file or text file in window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, authentication

How to prompt up user and password prompt for executable file or text file in window?

Want to pop up user authentication before using some program files application installed by its owner.

And pop up user authentication user and password prompt before opening cmd.exe and text file

Even for normal user and its owner to use user account authenticated before running cmd.exe

Is it possible Using window security assignment techniques or gpedit to do

Want to do like right click run as  administrator
But this doing is for normal user

I had tried add authenticed user and remove heritance of desktop user and remove desktop user. But still can not pop up credential message box

I had checked gpedit.msc has “all restricted package” this name but can not find it when using for normal folder text file security.

I find most company can not do this for normal user to pop up credential for cmd.exe , will this influence window system ?
Because I feel this prompt can prevent virus.

Comment: Prompts are pretty simple, depending on the language you're using. This question, however, A) lacks any clue as to what code this will be running in, B) fails to indicate what has been tried so far, C) fails to list any research done prior to asking, D) neglects to include any context regarding the sorts of systems and environments will is expected to function within. We are not a script or code writing service.

Comment: Tags show the clues. Is it possible Using window security assignment techniques or gpedit to do ?